# Proof that metric-Cauchy sequences = seminorm-Cauchy sequences on Fréchet spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I am trying to prove the following statement from the book *Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics* by V. Moretti:

> A sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in N} \subset X$ is Cauchy for a distance $d$ in a locally
> convex metrisable space $X$ if and only if it is Cauchy for every seminorm $p$ generating
> the topology: for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N_\epsilon^{(p)} \in \mathbb N$ such that $p(x_n −x_m ) < \epsilon$ whenever $n,m > N_\epsilon^{(p)} $. Consequently, completeness does not actually depend on the distance used to generate the locally convex topology.

**How can we prove this?**

---

If a sequence is Cauchy for $d$, then it will eventually lie in some ball $B_{d,\delta}(x)$ for any $\delta>0.$ Somehow we need to use this fact to show that it will eventually lie in some ball $B_{p,\epsilon}(y)$ for any fixed $p\in P,\epsilon>0.$ I'm sure the result will rely on $d$ and $P$ generating the same topologies, but I don't see how to link the two. We can always nest a metric-open set in a seminorm-open set, and vice versa, but this still doesn't lead me to an obvious solution.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133157/completeness-condition-for-fr%C3%A9chet-space) post contains a proof that completeness of any metric generating the same topology as $P$ guarantees completeness of all such metrics. But the statement here involves seminorms, so it is not an equivalent claim, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the metric is translation invariant.
Let $(x_n)$ be Cauchy in  the metric and $\epsilon >0$. If $p$ is a semi norm generating the topology  then $\{x: p(x) <\epsilon\}$ contains an open all $B_d(0,\delta)$. For $n,m$ sufficiently large $x_n-x_m \in B_d(0,\delta)$ and hence $p(x_n-x_m) <\epsilon$.

Converse follows from  the fact that $B_d(0,\epsilon)$ contains a set of the type $\{x:p_i(x) <\epsilon_i, 1\leq i \leq N\}$ for some positive integer $N$, some posotive numbers $\epsilon_i$ and some $p_i$'s.

Comment: The argument uses that the metric is translation invariant (so that $d(0,x_n-x_m)=d(x_n,x_m)$). Without that invariance the statement is wrong. For example, the metric $d(x,y)=\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)$ on $\mathbb R$ induces the usual topology but $x_n=n$ defines a $d$-Cauchy sequence which is not $|\cdot|$-Cauchy.

Comment: @Jochen Surely, I did assume that the metric  is translation invariant since that is a natural assumption in metrizable locally convex spaces.

Comment: Right, but there is a funny result of Victor Klee (answering a question of Banach) that a metrizable topological vector space is complete with respect to every translation invariant metric inducing the topology if there is some (not translation invariant) complete metric inducing the topology.

Comment: @Jochen So is the statement quoted from the book incorrect without unless we restrict to translation-invariant metrics? In other words, could there exist non-translation-invariant metrics inducing the same topology, but for which the statement is false?

Comment: @WillG Yes, Jochen has provided a counter-example is his comment.

Comment: @Jochen Could you mention any reference to this result by Victor Klee?

Comment: The article is Invariant metrics in groups (solution of a problem of Banach).
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 3 (1952), 484–487.
You can find the result also in Köthe's book *Topological Vector Spaces I*.